# Generating Record Ids in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, uuid, record

Using the UUID data type with its 256 chars seems like overkill, while assigning an auto-increment int4 seems less robust.

Is there a more robust way to assign a record id without using uuid or an auto-increment int4?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "robust". I mean strictly speaking from byte size the answer is correct, and it's a damn good attempt. If so, I would highly suggest editing the title to read "Is there a primary key between int4 and uuid?" that's the only thing the answer addresses.

Comment: Thanks, in retrospect ( this post is more than 2 years old) I think I was trying to understand if there was a way to create an id that was unique locally but also could be unique at a wider level as well. I know better now where I would just use the SERIAL auto-increment id and use the table's column name to guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UUID has a fixed size of 16 bytes:

```
=> select typlen from pg_type where oid = 'uuid'::regtype;
 typlen 
--------
     16
```

With `int4`, values have to be between `-2147483648` and `2147483647`.

If that's too narrow, consider the 8-byte `int8`, which goes from `-9223372036854775808` to `9223372036854775807`. Postgres sequences (`CREATE SEQUENCE...`) use that range.

`BIGSERIAL` is equivalent to declaring an `int8` column tied to a sequence.

Comment: Verite, thanks! I guess I was asking if there was a recommended approach as well? Are int fields fine, or is there another varchar id field that's smaller than uuid similar to Salesforce's record Ids.